# How do I read these graphs on the datasheet for an ssr?

Tags: datasheet

[image]

Specifically, I do not understand how to use the graph on the right. The full datasheet can be found [here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/404/s-13904.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph on left is showing you power dissipation as a function of load current for different duty cycles; full-on and 50%. The right hand graph is showing you for different thermal resistances (each line) what Tcase_max will be for a given ambient temperature. The datasheet is somewhat ambiguous on how those thermal resistance characteristics were determined, I imagine it depends on the heatsink you use, with 6C/W being no heatsink.

Comment: What is Tcase_max?

Comment: @wesanyer Max case temperature of the SSR.

Comment: Max _allowable_ or max temperature it will reach?

Comment: I believe max it will  reach. The datasheet does clearly state that the max temperature is 100C.